# How to hook Cucumber-Java life cycle

Tags: java, cucumber, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-java

I need a way to execute some code before each cucumber scenarios start and know which scenario is about to start, to make the executed code specific to this scenario.

I have try to override the Cucumber runner to create a hook without success.
Do you have any solution for me ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anything you write inside `@Before` is executed before every Scenario. Then, you could get especific scenario info using `getName()` for instance.

```
@Before
public void before(Scenario scenario) {
    String scenarioName = scenario.getName();
}
```

Take a look to [this](https://github.com/morvader/WebDriverExamples/tree/master/src/test/java/cucumber/Steps/Google) example I've made and see working Hooks.